# less with "update file" like functionality

Tags: bash, less, watch

I want to watch a file that gets overwritten every 5 minutes with `less`. How can I make `less` follow the new file descriptor instead of keeping the old one displayed? `watch "cat file"` won't do it because the file is too long to fit into one terminal window.

Comment: "Follow" implies following the end of the file. You may want to clarify that your file gets overwritten and you are interested in reopening it.

Comment: I meant following the file descriptor, as it is defined in `tail -f`'s man page. But nevertheless I have clarified my question.

Comment: Use `less --follow-name` see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74287/112522

Comment: Appears from the comments to answers that he wants a full-blown "less" that is running and operating on the "current version" of a certain large file (i.e. at the top)...

Answer (score 11):

You can get this effect by issuing the `F` command (`Shift+F`) while viewing the file in `less`. To stop following and switch back to paging, press `Ctrl+C`

Since your file only changes every 5 minutes, you could also use `tail -f` and specify a longer sleep time with `-s` (defaults to 1 second). For instance,

```
tail -f -s 60 myfile
```

checks `myfile` for output every 60 seconds.

EDIT: Due to misleading question, the above answer was unsatisfactory. Second attempt follows:

To re-open the same file in `less` every 5 minutes, try this:

```
while true; do ( sh -c 'sleep 600 && kill $PPID' & less myfile ); done
```

This will spawn a subshell which backgrounds another shell process instructed to kill its parent process after 5 minutes. Then it opens the file with `less`. When the backgrounded shell command kills the parent subshell, it kills all its children, including the "less" command. Then the loop starts the process over again.

The only easy way I know of to kill this is to kill the terminal your original shell is in. If that's unacceptable, you can use the "killfile" trick:

```
touch killfile
while [ -f killfile]; do stuff; done
```

To stop doing `stuff`, `rm` the killfile in another shell.

Comment: This is only partially useful for my case. The watched file is very big the updated information at the top. It is no "scrolling" log file. Shift+F immediately scrolls to the end of the file...

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify. I edited my answer to answer this, too.

Comment: `watch -n 1 less <filename>`

Comment: appears `watch -n 1 less <fiename>` is the equivalent of `watch -n 1 head -n40 <filename>` (i.e. less piped in becomes same as cat, but watch shows you the topmost lines) FWIW...so it does get you the top lines anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar in `vim`.

Start a server session of `vim`:

```
vim -R --servername refresh_session
```

Then in another console, monitor the file for updates and tell the vim session to reload the file as soon as it gets updated:

```
inotifywait -e close_write -m your_log_file | while read filename events; do
    vim --servername refresh_session --remote $filename
done
```

A few gotchas.

- This will of course not work if your `vim` is not compiled with the `clientserver` feature in.
- `inoifywait` will stop working when the file gets deleted. So I hope your file gets overwritten. It is possible to work around that, too, of course.

And if you want to have a more `less`-like experience, you can use the `less` macros to get your `less` key bindings in `vim`.

```
/usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/less.sh --servername refresh_session
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this command:
tail -f file

Answer (score 0):

Tail is your friend. "tail -f filename" will show you new lines when they appear.

Or if you are looking for changes made in the middle of the file, maybe run a script every few minutes to make a copy of the file to a temp location and do a diff on it?

Comment: It was quite clear even in the original post that there was a "new file".  Therefore the file descriptor would have changed but `tail -f` would still read the old one.

Comment: I don't think that's very fair. To be crystal clear, we need to look at the original, unedited post, because if you look at the date of my answer, that's the question I was answering. In that unedited question, my answer makes perfect sense. http://serverfault.com/posts/445899/revisions

Comment: I did check the revisions.  Keywords "new file".

Answer (score 0):

I found an old, but very good "less" like program (a "pager"). It has a "R" command that refresh the file.

It's called **"lv"**, You can install it on Ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt install lv
```

However, it seems to have no autoreload feature.